# MYSQL EXTRACTVALUE with "<" Less Than Operator returns NULL?

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSQL with the EXTRACTVALUE command, and the below code returns NULL when using the "<" Less Than Operator. But the ">" Greater Than Operator works as intended. Why?

```
select EXTRACTVALUE('<TrackerQuery>
  <Column>*</Column>
  <View> view_sms_speqs</View>
  <Filters>
    <Filter>
      <FilterColumn>DateTested</FilterColumn>
      <FilterOperator><</FilterOperator>
      <FilterValue>2019-04-18</FilterValue>
    </Filter>
  </Filters>
</TrackerQuery>', CONCAT('//TrackerQuery//Filters//Filter[', 1, ']//FilterOperator'));
```

Comment: Try enclosing the date in single quotes.

Comment: Just to be clear, this works:

 select EXTRACTVALUE('<TrackerQuery>
  <Column>*</Column>
  <View> view_sms_speqs</View>
  <Filters>
    <Filter>
      <FilterColumn>DateTested</FilterColumn>
      <FilterOperator>></FilterOperator>
      <FilterValue>2019-04-18</FilterValue>
    </Filter>
  </Filters>
</TrackerQuery>', CONCAT('//TrackerQuery//Filters//Filter[', 1, ']//FilterOperator'));

Comment: You appear to comparing something to 2019 minus 4 minus 18. So > will probably work.

Comment: Well if you run this in MYSQL, you will see the first query returns NULL, which is invalid. The 2nd query posted above, returns the intended value, which is ">". 

So, there is something about this EXTRACTVALUE function that doesn't like the "<" character. I have read the documentation, and I am not sure why. Its almost like I need an escape character.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the content `<tag><</tag>` is not valid, resulting in `NULL` being returned. This is mentioned in the documentation for [`EXTRACTVALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue):

> `NULL` is returned if `xml_frag` contains elements which are not properly nested or closed, and a warning is generated, as shown in this example: [...]

You will see in the following example that there was an error/warning when you use `<` as a content because it looks like it is the start of a new XML element.

```
mysql> SELECT EXTRACTVALUE('<abc><def><</def></abc>', '//abc//def');
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| EXTRACTVALUE('<abc><def><</def></abc>', '//abc//def') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                   |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1525 | Incorrect XML value: 'parse error at line 1 pos 13: '<' unexpected (ident or '/' wanted)' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Interesting enough, the value `&lt;` is not working as it should.

```
mysql> SELECT EXTRACTVALUE('<abc><def>&lt;</def></abc>', '//abc//def');
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| EXTRACTVALUE('<abc><def>&lt;</def></abc>', '//abc//def') |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| &lt;                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when you put it in a CDATA block, you will get the correct value.

```
mysql> SELECT EXTRACTVALUE('<abc><def><![CDATA[<]]></def></abc>', '//abc//def');
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| EXTRACTVALUE('<abc><def><![CDATA[<]]></def></abc>', '//abc//def') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| <                                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. That does work. Just to be clear, I am not the main developer on this, he is out on vacation, so I am trying to help in his place.